# HTML Что делать если текст пишется в столбик?

Tags: html

Вот код:

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">

      <nav class=nav>
        <a class="nav_link">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
        <a class="nav_link">ДОНАТ</a>
        <a class="nav_link">ФОРУМ</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Текст пишется вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно в строку! Что делать?

Comment: 1. Например расширение экрана маленькое. 2. Смотрите стили через панель разработчика. Наверняка что-то где-то переопределено

Comment: Если запустить ваш код в том виде, в котором вы его показали, то всё пишется замечательно в строку. Приведите [mcve], который будет демонстрировать проблему

Answer (score 0):

1. Например расширение экрана маленькое. И, например, какой-нибудь подключенный бутстрап определяет формат вывода для разных размеров.
2. Смотрите стили через панель разработчика. Наверняка что-то где-то переопределено

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не уверен, что такой вопрос-ответ имеет пользу для базы знаний...

Comment: Я не уверен вообще, что жизнь имеет какую-то пользу :D

Answer (score -1):

У класса  nav пропущены кавычки
nav class=nav

Comment: Их можно не писать уже несколько лет как

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, их всегда можно было не писать, если нет пробелов и не xml

Comment: @Grundy ну я ж говорю несколько лет :D